# How is it possible to configure the display on a Macbook to shrink icons like this?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Below is a picture of two Macbook laptops. The one on the left conforms to every Macbook I've seen. The one on the right has all of the system icons and fonts slightly too small to be comfortable. However, to the best of my knowledge, this isn't something you can edit. You can change the scaling of the entire display, but as noted they are both on the default settings there:

[image: Photo of two Mac laptops with identical configurations but with different screen scaling]

How is it possible to change this setting?

Both computers are on the same version of macOS Ventura.

Comment: What resolution is each laptop set to? That could be a big indicator of what you are experiencing.

Comment: Per the screenshot they are both set to the default. Unless that's not what that screen shows?

Comment: The "default" for one monitor can be different for another monitor. What are the **actual** numbers for the resolutions of each monitor?

Comment: They are identical monitors (the built in retina screens from two identical macbook pros). both are 1792x1120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following method is not available to versions prior to macOS 14 Sonoma (it's a new feature).**

---

It's all a matter of text size. If you look in *System Settings > Accessibility > Display > Text size*, you should notice a difference between the two Macs. Here is how the text and icons (look at the icon in the sidebar) look like with 9pt text size:

[image]

And here is how they look like with 24pt text size:

[image]

The icons' size also change along the text size, just check for that setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's a thing anymore? https://imgur.com/q18ocGt

Comment: @Henry Ah, yes, you're on Ventura. This is a new feature that appeared with macOS 14 Sonoma.

Comment: This is (or will be) the answer. Thank you @Thinkr

Comment: @henry You're welcome! Glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: Text size is no longer an option in accessibility settings but you can change sidebar icon size under the appearance settings in control panel.

Comment: It's actually not *yet* an option ;) Is it possible for you to update to macOS Sonoma?